# Get Value to Integer

Tags: java, string, integer

How to get value of an object and store it in variable int? In string I do this:

```
String k = s_extend.getValue().toString();
```

How about in int?

Comment: have you ever heard `Integer.parseInt()` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Integer.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) or [Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29); unless there's more to your question that would be something like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "1";
  int a = Integer.valueOf(str);                 // java.lang.Integer return(ed)
  int b = Integer.parseInt(str);                // primitive (int) return(ed)
  System.out.printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
}
```

On my machine, running this gives

```
a = 1, b = 1
```